# LCD screen suddenly displaying and updating inaccurately

Tags: lcd

For the final project of my Arduino course, I have decided to make an alarm clock. The actual clock part was easy enough, but when I wired my buttons up, I accidentally loosened a few wires that a classmate with an identical kit helped me wire up. And although that is resolved now, the halves of my screen are flipped and the second ticker is now only updating every 5 seconds with the same code, even when I comment out unrelated code and reupload. I triple checked the wiring and moving wires around didn't do much either, so I have no idea what is causing this glitch, but hope one of you guys can help me figure it out. Here are some images for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzrYM.jpg and my code is below:

````
#include <IRremoteInt.h>
#include <ir_Lego_PF_BitStreamEncoder.h>
/*
 * VSS: GND
 * VDD: 5v
 * V0: Potentiometer
 * RS: D1
 * RW: GND
 * E: D2
 * D4: D4
 * D5: D5
 * D6: D6
 * D7: D7
 * A: 5v
 * K: GN/>
 */

//Variables to make the time work
int hour = 11;
int minute = 59;
int second = 40;
int flag = 1;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn();
  irrecv.blink13(true);
  lcd.begin(16, 2); // initialize lcd width width and height
  lcd.clear();
}
void loop() {
// Print the time and make sure there are always 2 digits
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    if (hour < 10)
      lcd.print ("0");
    lcd.print(hour);
  lcd.setCursor(2,0);
    lcd.print(":");
  lcd.setCursor(3,0);
    if (minute < 10)
      lcd.print ("0");
    lcd.print(minute);
  lcd.setCursor(5,0);
    lcd.print(".");
  lcd.setCursor(6,0);
  if (second < 10)
    lcd.print ("0");
  lcd.print (second);
  lcd.setCursor(10,0);
    if (flag == 0)
      lcd.print ("AM");
    if (flag == 1)
      lcd.print ("PM");
}```
````

Comment: What do you mean? I noticed that my links aren't working properly, so I'll try again via imgur. [link](https://imgur.com/a/zBUQgkz) Hope this works. Took the best pictures I could of my wiring and output.

Comment: And the code that displays the characters: 
```lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    if (hour < 10)
      lcd.print ("0");
    lcd.print(hour);
  lcd.setCursor(2,0);
    lcd.print(":");
  lcd.setCursor(3,0);
    if (minute < 10)
      lcd.print ("0");
    lcd.print(minute);
  lcd.setCursor(5,0);
    lcd.print(".");
  lcd.setCursor(6,0);
  if (second < 10)
    lcd.print ("0");
  lcd.print (second);
  lcd.setCursor(10,0);
    if (flag == 0)
      lcd.print ("AM");
    if (flag == 1)
      lcd.print ("PM");```
Hope that clarifies things enough.

Comment: Alright, post is updated. Better now?

Comment: the picture showing `. 04 AM 01 : 00 ` is not useful if you do not say what you expect it to display instead .... what should the display be showing exactly?

Comment: Oh, right. It should display "1:00.04 AM". It was before, but after my little complication, the screen is flipped. Like the code is the same as before, setting the hour to 0,0, minute to 3,0, second to 6,0 and the flag to 10,0.

Comment: it is more than flipped ... look very carefully ... when debugging, it is important to observe the unexpected results in detail

Comment: what do you see if you run `lcd.print ("0123456789abcdef");`? ... no other lcd.print() code

Comment: you should also pay attention to the expected results ...  "1:00.04 AM" is missing the leading zero

Comment: if the code displays correct text in incorrect places, then it is a sofware issue ... if the wires were crossed, then incorrect text would show up